# monotonicity of $ \sqrt[n]{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, monotone-functions

I don't understand the following proof that shows that $ \sqrt[n]{x}$ on the positive reals is increasing monotonously.

It assumes that for two positive reals x and y, we have $ \sqrt[n]{x} \leq  \sqrt[n]{y}$. Inductivley it shows than that $ x \leq y $.

In my understanding a function $f$ is increasing monotonously iff $x \leq y \Longrightarrow f(x) \leq f(y)$. The proofs gives the other direction. Is the proof still valid because of the bijectivity of the function?

Comment: If $p$ and $q$ are some propositions then $p\rightarrow q$ is equivalent to $\textit{not } q \rightarrow \textit{not } p$. Defining $q:="x^{1/n} > y^{1/n}"$ and $p:= "x > y"$ gives you the path to the result

Answer (score 4):

Since $\sqrt[n]x\leqslant\sqrt[n]y\implies x\leqslant y$, then $x>y\implies\sqrt[n]x>\sqrt[n]y$. Therefore, and since asserting $P\implies Q$ is equivalent to asserting that $\neg Q\implies\neg P$, $x\mapsto\sqrt[n]x$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning explicitly that this is because the statement "$P$ implies $Q$" is equivalent to "not $Q$ implies not $P$". See [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).

Comment: @Joe It's done.

Comment: Hi prof. Please can you see if I have done some mistakes on my last question? Thank you very much

Comment: @Sebastiano Do you mean [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4224542/446262)?

Comment: Yes. It is correct. Thank you again

Comment: @Sebastiano I am not competent enough to answer that question.

Comment: But is it written very bad to received a simple answer to received DOWN VOTES? THANKS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128598/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-sebastiano).

Answer (score 2):

Since the domain is totally ordered, for all $x$ and $y$ either $x<y$ or $y\le x$, but not both at the same time. Since $\sqrt[n]y\le \sqrt[n]x$ implies $y\le x$ by the lemma you've proved, $x<y$ and $\sqrt[n]y\le \sqrt[n]x$ cannot be simultaneously true. This means that $x<y$ implies $\neg(\sqrt[n]y\le \sqrt[n]x)$. Since the codomain is totally ordered as well, $\neg(\sqrt[n]y\le \sqrt[n]x)$ is equivalent to $\sqrt[n]x<\sqrt[n]y$.